# Screen flickering on 16.04 TLS 1 When the laptop is on battery

Tags: graphics, screen

I am new to Ubuntu. Installed ubuntu 16.04 TLS 1 on my HP 2005AX which is powered by AMD processor and AMD graphics. Now my laptop is flickering when it's on battery. If I connect charger then works totally fine. Please suggest the solution. I searched forums but could not find a suitable solution.

update: Actually it's with all the Linux distro. I installed Mint os, Fedora but the same issue.

Comment: had same issue in past might be hardware issue,  problem my be with screen or battery.. try connecting external monitor is see weather u see flickring on external display...

Answer (score 0):

If it happens when at the BIOS setup screen (or in memory test, freedos, etc.) it might be a hardware issue: the battery is defective and cannot deliver enough power.

Comment: It does not seems to be happening on Bios. But when i am running windows everything works perfectly fine. I don't think this is the hardware issue, anyway will re install some of linux distro and try again.